# How to change the location of an icon of the Drawer Menu

Tags: java, android

i would like to know how to change the location of one icon in my drawer menu.

What I have is this layout:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcRiN.png)

but what I am looking for is something like this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iWkB.png)

The code that I am using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_perfil"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_perfil"
        android:title="Perfil" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_configuracion"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_configuracion"
        android:title="Configuración" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_acercade"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_acercade"
        android:title="Acerca de" />
</group>




<item android:title="Cuenta">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_salir"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_salir"
            android:title="Salir" />
</item>
```

I was wondering if someone of you could help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. Probable the code is not the most
appropriated but it actually works

- Solution
  I have just add some 'dummy code' to create some empty items. Basically what I am doing is creating with no title, no icon and no id, so my final code is the same one, but adding

  ```
      <item android:title=" " />
  ```

as many times as I need before than my last real item.

I hope that i will be useful for any of you.